# Jest error running a file with idx operator

Tags: react-native, babeljs, jestjs

[image]

I am using the existential function idx from facebook https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2017/03/13/idx-the-existential-function.html with babel, react native and jest. Configuration for development and production is fine, but when running tests some of the developers in the team got the following error:

```
The body of the arrow function supplied to `idx` must be a single expression 
(without curly braces).
```

We make use of yarn and yarn.lock so it is really weird that some we have the error and some not.

Any hints on where the problem must be?

I tried updating babel, changing babel configuration, upgrading jest or react-native.

EDIT: This error only happens when I try to run jest with coverage. I always use the package's jest@19.0.2

Thanks